# How to convert shapely geometry linestring into shapefile?

Tags: python, shapefile, shapely, rasterio

I have extracted linestring from Landsat images. now, I am literally stuck what to do? I want to convert it into shapefile. It is actually coastline geometry.

```
   **In[1]:** type(water_lines_smooth)
    **Out[1]:** list
    **In[2]:** print(water_lines_smooth)
    **Out[2]:**
    [<shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x2d11cd01c08>,
     <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x2d11019f048>,
     <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x2d11cd09d08>,
     <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x2d11cceac08>,
     <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x2d11ca7d0c8>,
     <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x2d11ca7d108>,
     <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x2d142747f88>,
     <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x2d142747ec8>,
     <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x2d142747088>,
     <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x2d11ca7d148>,
     <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x2d142747e48>,
     <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x2d142747d08>,
     <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x2d142747d48>,
     <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x2d142747cc8>,
     <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x2d142747408>,
     <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x2d142747e08>,...

    **In[3]:** [{'geometry': x.__geo_interface__} for x in water_lines_smooth]
    **Out[3]:**
    {'geometry': {'type': 'LineString',
       'coordinates': ((377205.43543222273, 2464301.85113062),
        (377235.43946816603, 2464301.85113062),
        (377235.43946816603, 2464241.855100152),
        (377205.43543222273, 2464241.855100152),
    (375315.1811677954, 2464391.8451763224),
        (375285.1771318521, 2464331.8491458544),
        (375225.1690599655, 2464331.8491458544),
        (375165.1609880789, 2464361.8471610886),....
I have tried to convert it into geodataframe but there is geometry column issue.


     **In[4]:** df=gpd.GeoDataFrame(water_lines_smooth)
     I**n[5]:** df.to_file("shapef.shp") 
    AttributeError: No geometry data set yet (expected in column 'geometry'.) –
```

is there any alternative way to get shapefile?

Comment: yes, I have. I have tried to convert to geodataframe , it says, there is no geometry. I think, I need to work on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is incomplete so impossible to tell whats wrong. But this is working when I try:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString
coords = [(377205.43543222273, 2464301.85113062),
        (377235.43946816603, 2464301.85113062),
        (377235.43946816603, 2464241.855100152),
        (377205.43543222273, 2464241.855100152),
        (375315.1811677954, 2464391.8451763224),
        (375285.1771318521, 2464331.8491458544),
        (375225.1690599655, 2464331.8491458544),
        (375165.1609880789, 2464361.8471610886)]

aline = LineString(coords)
bline = LineString([(c[0]+100, c[1]) for c in coords])
d = {'col1': ['name1','name2'], 'geometry': [aline, bline]}
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(d, crs="EPSG:32618") #(change epsg)
df.to_file('/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/lines1234.shp')
```

Answer (score 0):

The shapely dont export to shapefile. I think that the geopandas do that due the Fiona. So, I recommend you to create a GeoDataFrame and then just create the shapefile with the method `geoDataFrame.to_file("<>.shp")`.

Comment: I am  still getting error     df=gpd.GeoDataFrame(water_lines_smooth) df.to_file("shapef.shp")     AttributeError: No geometry data set yet (expected in column 'geometry'.)